# Making a user specific product install?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

We have got an existing InstallShield InstallScript MSI install project that we are trying to modify in order to make it so we can give a customer an install that will only work with their specific serial number for use with our new automated check for updates feature. We already have a mechanism in place that evaluates a customer's serial number and other credentials at install time that were hoping to be able to still use.  Right now the best idea I've got is to hash or otherwise obfuscate the users credentials in a file and insert the file into a zip of the installer package (MSI, CAB files, InstallShield specific files, etc) that the installer can later consume at runtime.  This however seems rather hokey to me.  Is there a better way of achieving the same goal?

EDIT:
So what we are going to wind up doing is encrypting the set of credentials that this install is only supposed to work for, and then including that in the update installer that gets distributed.  The installer will then unencrypt the credentials for use during install so we can check that the user trying to install the software is the user we want to install the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear exactly what you're asking for. It's possible that using  [setupini.exe](http://flexerasoftware.force.com/articles/en_US/INFO/Q107253) to update the command-line to pass some extra properties to Windows Installer would do all you need.

If instead you're looking to make this secure, Windows Installer's use of fully open formats makes it hard to prevent a crafty end-user from accessing the files it carries. You can make it hard to install certain features the normal way, or even block execution on a serial number check, but the files can still be extracted manually.

Because of this, or perhaps because the company selling InstallShield also sells in-product licensing solutions, they would tend to suggest using licensing in the application as a less hokey alternative to most of this.

Comment: When a user checks our website for a newer version of our software they supply their license credentials, we would like to have the installer they download only install our software if the user enters the credentials they used to check for the update in the first place as opposed to any valid set of credentials that may happen to be in the wild. (Don't ask why, I just do what management tells me.. :-/)  We already have a licensing system in place so the InstallShield solution is off the table unfortunately.
Thanks for the tip about setupini.exe btw :-)

Comment: OK, then I think within those bounds, without increasing the difficulty of implementation significantly, I'd suggest setupini.exe. Note that it is not impenetrable, and consider carefully whether to pass credentials or hashes of credentials into the MSI given the presence of log files. Don't forget about updating digital signatures, assuming you use them. (And yes, for this scenario unless different people receive truly different bits, I'd prefer to question why. `:)`)

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer to my question because even though this is not what I wound up doing, the advice is still solid.